# jquery mobile prevent browser reload

Tags: jquery-mobile, reload

I added data to the page in Ajax and then I changed to the page
`$.mobile.changePage('#postDetails', { transition: "slide" })`
but then when I refresh the browser all the contents I added with the Ajax is not there any more.

Comment: can you provide ajax calls/functions you used ?

Comment: $.ajax({
        url: postDetailsUrl,
        type: "post",
        data: {id: id},
        success: function (data) {
            $('#commentList').html(data);
            $('#commentsNum').text($('#commentList .comment').length);
            initCommentPage();
            $.mobile.changePage('#postDetails',{transition: "slide"})
        }
    });

Answer (score 0):

refreshing a page will remove Ajax data, to resolve that issue you need to add your Ajax call inside pageshow event like following

```
$(document).on("pageshow","#postDetails",function(){
 $.ajax({
    url: postDetailsUrl,
    type: "post",
    data: {id: id},
    beforeSend: function () {
        $.mobile.loading("show");
    },
    complete: function () {
        $.mobile.loading("hide");
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $('#commentList').html(data);
        $('#commentsNum').text($('#commentList .comment').length);
        initCommentPage();            
    },
    error: function (requestObject, error, errorThrown) {
        alert("Error in communication");
    }
 });
})
```

now this ajax request is in pageshow event so every time popstDetails page is shown it will make a ajax call to postDetailsUrl and show the data in commentList element.

to know more about page events see gajotres's [blog](http://www.gajotres.net/page-events-order-in-jquery-mobile-version-1-4-update/)

Comment: Thanks Arpit, but how I can store the id?

Comment: store in browser's localstorage.

to set value `localStorage.setItem('idkey', idValue);`

and to get value `idvalue = localStorage.getItem('idkey');`

click [for more](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) description